# Redirecting request for non-existent s3 bucket to different bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There is a bucket with some world readable content, which is being referenced from many places. We have migrated the contents of the bucket to a new bucket.
Now, we need remove the old bucket, but we cannot remove the endpoints/reference for the objects which were generated in the old bucket.

for example:

Old bucket name: xxx-yyy

Sample endpoint : https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx-yyy/facebook.png

New bucket name: abc-pqr

Sample endpoint : https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc-pqr/facebook.png

Any request coming to non-existent `xxx-yyy` bucket should redirect to `abc-pqr` bucket. We do not want to remove the endpoints, we just want to redirect the request coming to the objects with the endpoint to the new bucket.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are referencing files directly in Amazon S3. This format of URL is not able to redirect requests.

Amazon S3 buckets have a capability called **Static Website hosting**, which gives additional capabilities such as default Index & Error pages, plus the ability to setup a [Webpage Redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html).

However, this requires a different URL to access your objects (eg `http://xxx-yyy/s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/facebook.png`). Given that you are unable to change your existing links, this would not be an option.

Your only option would be to create web pages in the original S3 bucket that use an [HTML redirect](https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/) to forward browsers to the new location.

Comment: We are going to remove the old bucket, so the option you have provided is not possible

Comment: Then your requirement is not possible either.

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup that's not possible. If you would have used AWS Cloudfront then you could have easily achieved that

Comment: Or if you specified your URL using a CNAME in Route53 or similar so that you could change the dns entry to the new bucket.